# Is there any way to auto compile es6 to es5 in yii2 asset bundles?

Tags: ecmascript-6, yii2, ecmascript-5

I am working on several sites that have IE11 users.  The sites are built using yii2 and make use of lots of ES6.  Rather then re-writing everything down to ES5, is there a plugin for yii2 that will do the work?  My first thought was babel but it doesn't seem to integrate into yii2.

Thanks

Comment: You won't be able to do that without Babel. The preferable way to do that is to pre-build all client-side JS scripts. Babel can also be used to build scripts on the fly https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation but this should never be done in production.

Comment: So the only way is to set up the watcher in webstorm, then re-aim all the asset bundles at the transcompiled versions?

Comment: It's up to you how Babel is called. It can be done in IDE or elsewhere. Yes, Yii assets should be aimed at processed JS files, not source.

Comment: Any way to convert code that is in the views and not in asset bundles?

Comment: No. At this point you should think of JS as of separate application that requires its own pipeline, not just as of 'asset'.